# Tinymce with textarea content inside editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-5

I have the following markup im trying to initialize.

```html
<textarea id="main">
    Some Text<br>
    <textarea class="foobar">[marker-123]</textarea>
</textarea>
```

Tinymce is stripping out the `[marker-123]` text from my sub textarea. I tried to keep it by doing the following but couldn't get it to work. Is there a better way to prevent Tinymce from stripping the contents of the inner textarea?

```js
tinymce.init({
    extended_valid_elements: 'textarea[*]',
    editor_deselector : "foobar",
    ...
});
```

Comment: I was little confused with stripping weather you mean trim of white spaces. If its like that. I guess selector with css class should start with dot(.) . https://codepen.io/PiyushXCoder/pen/eYvBZPM . See this and if it works well for you.

Comment: Aha, yeah, that's the culprit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector with CSS class should start with dot(.). That is instead of calling the textarea with `foobar` you should use `.foobar`.